# How to get date format from a date string?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I use `dateparser.parse` to turn a string date into a `datetime` object:

```
>>> dateparser.parse(u'22 Décembre 2010')
datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 22, 0, 0)
```

But now I want to create new dates with the same string format.  How can I get this?

```
>>> get_date_pattern(u'22 Décembre 2010')
'%d %B %Y'
```

Edit: I'll clarify that I don't know what the string format is (I'm iterating through a list of many date strings, and for each one I want to create a new date in the same format).  I'm not looking to convert a datetime object to string, I'm looking to take a formatted string and determine what that format is.

Comment: `datetime.datetime.strftime(d,'%d %B %Y')`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is natively possible. Differentiating between mm/dd/yyyy and dd/mm/yyyy would be difficult for certain dates.

Comment: As I understand it, dateparser.parse just iterates through a huge number of date string formats (probably in some prioritized order) and returns the first match.  I'm just looking to get that format that dateparsers finds a match for.

Comment: I guess its time to read the source. The code is hosted on [github](https://github.com/scrapinghub/dateparser) and you may be able to interact with developers there.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a 3rd party lib dateutil.

```
from dateutil import parser
dt = parser.parse("06 April, 2019")
```

To install this, you can do:

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

Comment: Beware that this does not work when your date string misses some component of the date eg OCT 2022 or 16 OCT

Answer (score -1):

From the [`datetime` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html):

> `datetime.strftime(format)`
>
> Return a string representing the date and
>   time, controlled by an explicit format string. For a complete list of
>   formatting directives, see section `strftime()` and `strptime()` Behavior.

Comment: My question wasn't clear.  I don't know what the string format is (I'm iterating through a list of many dates in many date formats), so I'm looking for a function that automatically figures out what the format is.